# PyQt Timeline Gui

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt, timeline

I need to make a timeline like this:

[image]

using PyQt for the gui.

Basically, this timeline is for a car. On the timeline is all the stages of production the car goes through with dates and to the left is the team(s) involved in that specific stage.

i.e the Testing stage starts on the 21st January and ends on the 4th February. It's team(s) are the Crash Test Team and the Demolition Crew

The Production stages ( Design , Development, Testing , Marketing etc) need to be scalable so if you drag the end of the Design production phase from the 8th of January to the 10th of Jan, all the other stages in Production get a 2 day offset.

Any ideas, reccomendations, experiences, advice would be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Since this hasn't got an answer yet, a quick suggestion - writing this from scratch in PyQt sounds like a lot of time and effort. The simple option is probably a spreadsheet. If you want more specific features, have a search to see if there's gantt chart software already out there.

Comment: For those finding this years later, I would first try QTableWidget, then QTableView using QStandardItemModel or QAbstractItemModel. Frankly I'd probably just do it in Excel. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, there are many ways to do this, but I would use QGraphicsView. I primarily use C++/Qt so can't comment how easy this would be to do in Python.

I would have each "stage" be a QGraphicsItem, and draw the Months/Days as the QGraphicsView background. I would override the mouse events for the graphics item to show appropriate cursors and resize it and its neighbours appropriately on mouse down/mouse move events.

This would be a fair amount of work. An easier approach would certainly be to use an existing control. A quick web search reveals KD Gantt from ICS ([link](http://www.ics.com/products/qt/kdgantt)) which is non-free but seems to have the facilities you need.

Comment: I looked into it a bit and it seemed I would have to use a QGraphicsView but now that I've read your answer I definatley will be going that route. Thanks for your advice P)

Comment: No problem. I did something slightly similar recently and found the [Elastic Nodes example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview-elasticnodes.html) to be very helpful to show how to draw a background and implement relationships between items on a graph.